# Android AVD: Device Disconnected Issue

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I use the latest Eclipse with ADT bundle.

I've been having this problem for some time now its rather annoying.

I start one of my AVD devices. Once its started, I right click and run as android application. Shortly after it starts another AVD device of a different device (a small phone). Not the one I had started previously.

I do notice sometimes it says on LogCat Device Disconnected -1

Only after closing both devices and then re-launching a device I want is when it works.

This is an annoyance because of the time it takes for device to boot. Is there some sort of way or ADB shell command to reconnect device.

Thanks for any help or advice given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from command line:

```
adb kill-server
```

and then

```
adb start-server
```